# Kotlin: For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method

Tags: kotlin

If I use `var charSet = 1..10` it works, but when I am using the below code, I'm getting this error.

```
var charSet = "A".."Z"
for (value in charSet) {    
  println("$value")  
}
```

> For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method.

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 5):

`charSet` is a `ClosedRange<String>` and that type doesn't have `iterator()` function (but ex. IntRange does). You can either change your range to `'A'..'Z'` or create an extension function `ClosedRange<String>.iterator()` which would return a `Iterator`. The error should then go away

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. Could you give me a sample code?

Comment: @Venkatesh_J Updated my answer. I think you actually want `'A'..'Z'` not `"A".."Z"`

Answer (score 4):

Its giving current output.Change your double quotes into single quotes

```
    var charSet = 'A'..'Z'
    for (value in charSet) {
        println("$value")
    }
```

Comment: Great. Its working now. I didnt expect, it would behave in this fashion. Thanks a lot Sasi and Mibac.

Answer (score 2):

To declare a string, we use double quotes and to declare a character, we use single quotes. You can iterate through characters and not strings. When you change your quotes to single, your code will run perfectly.